# CrudRepository not saving data in CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add some default data the moment the application starts through commandlinerunner but the .save function from crudrepository is not saving the data. I have tried this in another commandlinerunner and it works fine. I'm not sure what is the problem in this class. Any help is appreciated!

My other class that runs has the following console output

```
Hibernate: insert into user (name, role, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Saved user:User [name=jyj123, id=1, role=Admin]
```

This class that doesn't work shows Hibernate: insert **** and Hibernate: Select****

CommandLineRunner class

```
@Component
public class FlightsRepositoryCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private FlightsRepository flightsRep;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d1 = df.parse("2020-12-10");
        Date d2 = df.parse("2020-12-11");
        Flights flights = new Flights("SQ404", "SIN", "LAX", "2045", "2140", "15h 55min", "Singapore Airlines", "$1050", d1, d2, false);
        flightsRep.save(flights);
        Date d3 = df.parse("2021-01-01");
        Date d4 = df.parse("2021-01-02");
        Flights flights1 = new Flights("UA356", "LAX", "SIN", "0045", "0940", "21h 30min", "United Airlines", "$941", d3, d4, false);
        flightsRep.save(flights1);
        Date d5 = df.parse("2020-09-15");
        Date d6 = df.parse("2020-09-16-");
        Flights flights2 = new Flights("EM544", "SIN", "LAX", "2045", "2140", "20h 35min", "Emirates", "$591", d5, d6, false);
        flightsRep.save(flights2);
        Date d7 = df.parse("2020-12-25");
        Date d8 = df.parse("2020-12-26");
        Flights flights3 = new Flights("SQ501", "SIN", "LAX", "2045", "2140", "19h 45min", "Singapore Airlines", "$1203", d7, d8, false);
        flightsRep.save(flights3);
        Date d9 = df.parse("2020-10-10");
        Date d10 = df.parse("2020-10-11");
        Flights flights4 = new Flights("MA403", "LAX", "SIN", "1945", "2340", "14h 55min", "Malaysia Airlines", "$2102", d9, d10, false);
        flightsRep.save(flights4);
    }

}
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Flights {

    @Id
    String flightNumber;
    String origin;
    String destination;
    String takeOffTime;
    String landingTime;
    String flightDuration;
    String airline;
    String price;
    @Future
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date takeOffDate;
    @Future
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date landingDate;
    boolean flightReturn;

    public boolean isFlightReturn() {
        return flightReturn;
    }

    public void setFlightReturn(boolean flightReturn) {
        this.flightReturn = flightReturn;
    }

    public Date getLandingDate() {
        return landingDate;
    }

    public void setLandingDate(Date landingDate) {
        this.landingDate = landingDate;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(String origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }


    public String getTakeOffTime() {
        return takeOffTime;
    }


    public void setTakeOffTime(String takeOffTime) {
        this.takeOffTime = takeOffTime;
    }

    public String getLandingTime() {
        return landingTime;
    }

    public void setLandingTime(String landingTime) {
        this.landingTime = landingTime;
    }

    public String getFlightDuration() {
        return flightDuration;
    }

    public void setFlightDuration(String flightDuration) {
        this.flightDuration = flightDuration;
    }

    public Date getTakeOffDate() {
        return takeOffDate;
    }

    public void setTakeOffDate(Date takeOffDate) {
        this.takeOffDate = takeOffDate;
    }

    protected Flights() {

    }

    public String getAirline() {
        return airline;
    }

    public void setAirline(String airline) {
        this.airline = airline;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Flights(String flightNumber, String origin, String destination, String takeOffTime, String landingTime,
            String flightDuration, String airline, String price, Date takeOffDate, Date landingDate,
            boolean flightReturn) {
        super();
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.takeOffTime = takeOffTime;
        this.landingTime = landingTime;
        this.flightDuration = flightDuration;
        this.airline = airline;
        this.price = price;
        this.takeOffDate = takeOffDate;
        this.landingDate = landingDate;
        this.flightReturn = flightReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flights [flightNumber=" + flightNumber + ", origin=" + origin + ", destination=" + destination
                + ", takeOffTime=" + takeOffTime + ", landingTime=" + landingTime + ", flightDuration=" + flightDuration
                + ", airline=" + airline + ", price=" + price + ", takeOffDate=" + takeOffDate + ", landingDate="
                + landingDate + ", flightReturn=" + flightReturn + "]";
    }
```

Comment: Can you post error trace ??

Comment: Instead of `CommandLineRunner` you can also try `ApplicationRunner`

Comment: From where do you know its not saved? Does an error occour? Have you enabled the logs to see hibernates actions?

Comment: @Patrick the console doesn't write hibernate: saved ***

Comment: @AvijitBarua There is no error, it just doesn't save

Comment: @FenzoxvYou better check whether data saved or not in db first!